# Why do I get Index was outside the bounds of the array when moving data to a text field

Tags: vb.net

This my code - this section is looking at a message from a NMEA GPS device

```
          Try
            degreeString = Words(3).Substring(0, 2)
            LatDD = CDec(degreeString)
            MinuteString = (Words(3).Substring(2, 8))
            LatDM = CDec(CInt(MinuteString) / 60)
            LatDecimalDegrees = LatDD + LatDM
            If Words(4) = "S" Then
                LatDecimalDegrees *= -1
            End If
           Catch ex As Exception
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            ErrorDisplay.Clear()
            ErrorDisplay.Text = ToString(errorCount)
            GPS_WordOK = False
            Exit Function
        End Try code here`Try
            degreeString = Words(3).Substring(0, 2)
            LatDD = CDec(degreeString)
            MinuteString = (Words(3).Substring(2, 8))
            LatDM = CDec(CInt(MinuteString) / 60)
            LatDecimalDegrees = LatDD + LatDM
            If Words(4) = "S" Then
                LatDecimalDegrees *= -1
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            errorCount = errorCount + 1
            ErrorDisplay.Clear()
            ErrorDisplay.Text = ToString(errorCount)
            GPS_WordOK = False
            Exit Function
        End Try
```

The error is thrown on this line in the exception processing

```
    ErrorDisplay.Text = ToString(errorCount)
```

the value of error_count is 49

I don't see where the array is implied in the failing line

The error which caused entry to the exception handler is thrown by the statement

```
    LatDM = CDec(CInt(MinuteString) / 60)
```

which has the string value 41*68028

I believe some noise on the line caused the decimal to be read as an asterisk and the division failed. This error recovery was successful 48 prior times over a 24 hour period.

Comment: Maybe not connected, but out of interest.  What is ToString(errorCount)?  I've never seen it used like that.  Normally see thing like errorCount.ToString()

Comment: try changing `CDec` to `CDbl`

Comment: Hi and thanks - Here is the MSDn citation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netcore-3.1, I use this in many programs, I use CDec since LatDm is defined as decimal. As a interim solution I am scanning the input data sentence replacing "*" with "." before splitting to Word()

Comment: You mean `[Something] = Convert.ToString(errorCount)`. `ToString(errorCount)` is `[Something] = [Your Form].ToString(errorCount)`. But you're probably trying to convert as: `[Something] = errorCount.ToString()`

Comment: OK - I have changed the line to read ErrorDisplay.Text = errorCount.ToString  - and am retesting - Still confused since the ErrorDisplay.Text = ToString(errorCount) works 40-60 times  .and VS does not complain about the syntax  . .  I looked in some of my other programs and I use ErrorDisplay.Text = CStr(errorCount)  which hasn't failed Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use either

ErrorDisplay.Text = errorCount.ToString

or

ErrorDisplay.Text = CStr(errorCount)